# I am trying to insert multiple rows dynamically in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table ACCOUNTS
(
     AccNo int, 
     CName char(25), 
     Balance int,
     Primary key(AccNo)
);

declare
    c char;
    b int;
begin
    for i in 1 .. 3
    loop
        insert into accounts values ( i, 'AccNo',&c,'Cname',&b,'Balance' );
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: while the potential answerers can try to run your query to check what's wrong, you should still write what's wrong with your query (e.g.: is there any error message? is the result not expected? what's the expected output vs your output?). This is so that this question may be helpful for other users who encounter same problem

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
DECLARE
        c char;
        b int;
    BEGIN 
      FOR i IN 1 .. 3
      LOOP
        sqlStat := 'INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS (AccNo, CName, Balance) VALUES( i, 'AccNo',&c,'Cname',&b,'Balance')';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlStat;
      END LOOP;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

`&` signifies a substitution variable. These are evaluated when the code is parsed and whatever value you substitute in will be put into the code as if you had done a find-replace operation on the code before executing it.

If you want to have multiple values in multiple rows then you can use use `INSERT ALL` and different substitution variables:

```sql
INSERT ALL
INTO accounts VALUES (1, 'AccNo', &c1, 'Cname', &b1, 'Balance')
INTO accounts VALUES (2, 'AccNo', &c2, 'Cname', &b2, 'Balance')
INTO accounts VALUES (3, 'AccNo', &c3, 'Cname', &b3, 'Balance')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Answer (score -1):

perhaps you are looking for;

```
insert into accounts values ( 1, 'AccNo',&c,'Cname',&b,'Balance' ), ( 2, 'AccNo',&c,'Cname',&b,'Balance' ), ( 3, 'AccNo',&c,'Cname',&b,'Balance' );
```

May you should do (I don't know about Oracle);

```
insert into accounts values ( 1, &c,&b,'Balance' ), ( 2, &c,&b,'Balance' ), ( 3, &c,&b,'Balance' );
```